# Gridview - Why am I getting SQL Command not properly ended

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, gridview

I am trying to create a simple gridview that displays one table from my Oracle DB and allows me to delete a row. I am currently getting the error 'SQL Command Not Properly Ended' and after looking around on here it seems that Oracle doesn't allow joins on update statements. But I am not joining or doing an update statement. Can anyone see where the issue is coming from? Thanks in advance.

[image: Error]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Configuration;

using System.Data.OracleClient;

namespace DatabaseTest
{
public partial class AvatarView : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }      
    protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string avatarID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string deleteSql = "DELETE FROM Avatar WHERE AvatarID = :AvatarID; ";

        using (var con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString3"].ConnectionStr‌​ing))
        using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(deleteSql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":AvatarID", OracleType.VarChar).Value = avatarID;
            con.Open();
            int deleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

Source code -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AvatarView.aspx.cs" Inherits="DatabaseTest.AvatarView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" DataKeyNames="AVATARID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" Height="422px" Width="1020px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AVATARID" HeaderText="AVATARID" SortExpression="AVATARID" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AVATARNAME" HeaderText="AVATARNAME" SortExpression="AVATARNAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="STRENGTH_CURR" HeaderText="STRENGTH_CURR" SortExpression="STRENGTH_CURR" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GENDER" HeaderText="GENDER" SortExpression="GENDER" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HOARD" HeaderText="HOARD" SortExpression="HOARD" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SPECIESID" HeaderText="SPECIESID" SortExpression="SPECIESID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USERID" HeaderText="USERID" SortExpression="USERID" />             
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />


        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM &quot;AVATAR&quot;"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding with the param name "AvatarID"

Comment: Can you elaborate, i'm still a beginner, what exactly does adding with param name mean? Where would I do this? Thanks @AlexK.

Comment: I mean `cmd.Parameters.Add("AvatarID", OracleType.VarChar).Value = avatarID;` - i.e. without the lead `:`

Comment: This looks like an awfully strange select command: `SELECT * FROM &quot;AVATAR&quot;`. Also you're using `System.Data.OracleClient`. That's deprecated. You should use the [Managed Oracle Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/), which is officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon from the SQL statement on this line:

```
string deleteSql = "DELETE FROM Avatar WHERE AvatarID = :AvatarID; ";
```